# combine files with similar substring in filename

Tags: bash

I would like to combine files that have similar ID before the FIRST underscore "_". Below is an example of two such files. I think `cat` is the tool to use.

in:

```
EIV105_S21_R1.fastq.gz 
EIV105_2_S117_R1.fastq.gz
EIV10_S13_R1.fastq.gz
EIV10_2_S109_R1.fastq.gz
```

out:

```
EIV105_R1.fastq.gz 
EIV10_R1.fastq.gz
```

Comment: What should happen to the contents of the files?

Comment: merge them, put on top of each other.

Comment: Yes, you can use simple `cat` to merge the `.gz` files with, e.g. `cat file1.gz file2.gz > filenew.gz` (you will get a total merged file, meaning unzipping will provide the contents of both `file1, file2` not two zip files `file1.gz, file2.gz`)

Comment: but I have 90 files, need a loop function.

Comment: Yes, I would `sort` then loop using a parameter expansion to isolate the first `..._` and the `sort | uniq` to obtain a unique list of prefixes. Then you can optimize compression with `cat "prefix_"* > previx.suffix`. (you will get better compression if you use `gzip -cd "prefix_"* > previx.suffix`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

suffix=R1.fastq.gz

find *_?*_$suffix | sed 's/_.*//' | sort -u |\
while read id; do
    cat "$id"_?*_$suffix > "$id"_$suffix
    # gzip -cd "$id"_?*_$suffix | gzip > "$id"_$suffix
done
```

- `find` lists the input filenames
- `sed` extracts the ids
- `sort` outputs only unique ids
- `while` loops over the unique ids (assuming they don't contain unusual characters like backslash or newline)
- `cat` creates outputs
- `gzip` may give better compression than cat

Comment: Thanks, this did not work for these two files: EIV93_2_S176_R1.fastq.gz, EIV93_S80_R1.fastq.gz

Comment: the EIV105-files were not combined.

Comment: just realised the `echo` will catenate all the filenames into a single line. replacing with `find`  or piping through `fmt -1` should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation on jhnc's answer using *process substitution* to feed the `while` loop that creates the combined gzip files, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

suffix=R.fastq.gz
while read -r prefix; do
    cat "${prefix}_"* > "$prefix.$suffix"
done < <(for i in *.gz; do echo ${i%%_*}; done | sort -u)
```

It uses the `for` loop to isolate and collect the unique prefixes for each existing gzip file in the current directory, and then redirects that unique list as input to the `while` loop.

(**note:** *process substitution*, e.g. `<(process)` is a *bashism* available in bash, but not in POSIX shell. When redirecting *process substitution* to fee the while loop, there must be a space between the redirection and process substitution, e.g. `< <(process)`)